# AsyncTask goes into wait state

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to cancel the Async Task on the particular condition.
I am doing the following stuff:

```
MyService.java

....
if(condition){

 asyncTask.cancel(true); // its return the true as well

}
...

MyAsynTask.java

...

protected Object doInBackground(Object... x) {
    while (/* condition */) {
      // work...
      if (isCancelled()){ // Here task goes in to wait state
 break;
  }
      else{
 //continue to download file

   }


    }
    return null;
 }
...
```

Using DDMS I found that task goes into wait State. Any suggestion to resolve this issue will be highly appreciated.
[image: Threads]

Thanks,
Yuvi

Comment: you don't need to check for it isCancelled() in doInBackground( method). Just check the condition n cancel it.

Comment: Task goes? Maybe thread goes? Where DDMS shows tasks state? If thread goes to wait state it is normal.

Comment: @Leonidos added Screen shot as well...  AsyncTask is the name of the thread only...

Comment: @UsamaSarwar I think it better to check the condition, of provided POJO in the Async Task.. if you check the some global variable then Synchronization condition may be occured. It might be possible that global variable or condition is changed by some other thread.

Comment: Well then, What I can think is @Leonidos is right, you are cancelling the task being within the task..that might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask is a piece of work for PoolExecutor. When you execute your first task Executor creates first thread and executes your task on it. After task execution is finished the thread is not deleted. It starts waiting for a new task.

So it is normal to see AsyncTask thread in wait state.

P.S. It's better not to use AsyncTask for longtime operation. Use your own executor or thread.

P.P.S. AsyncTask uses single thread executor since 4.x. Be careful )

Comment: Yes, Async Tasks works sequentially by default, and we can also run them parallel. But if task is finished it should come on `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean). Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)

Comment: if you cancel task onPostExecute won't be called.

Comment: I did so already, check the above code sample.. That was the counter regarding `wait` as per your views.

Comment: I checked your code and it works fine. After I canceled the task, task's onCancel is called, task is finished, and thread goes to wait state.. everything works as it should. What part of it you do not like?

Answer (score 0):

after you explicitly call `asyncTask.cancel(true);`, the `onCancelled()` method is called. Try overriding the following method:

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    //what you want to do when the task was cancelled.
}
```

Comment: you never Know when onCaneclled will be called, its always better idea to check `isCancelled()` in `doInBackground` method.