# Internal AsyncTask class to poll URL periodically

Tags: android, android-asynctask

**Problem:**
What I am trying to do is have an AsyncTask poll a URL in the background periodically (every 5 seconds or so), and if specific data is received, disable an element on the activity. I have tried creating a separate class and using onPostExecute to run the method from the activity class to disable an ImageView, but I run into issues. I cannot call that method from the other class unless I make it static, and if I do declare it static, I cannot access the ImageView using findViewById.

**Current status:**
I have a TimerTask running my RetrieveColorTask that extends AsyncTask periodically every 5 seconds. But this causes exceptions as it tries to execute the same thread multiple times.

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    final RetrieveColorTask task = new RetrieveColorTask();
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, true);
    AsyncTask.Status status = task.getStatus();

    TimerTask doTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(status.compareTo(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) == 0)
                task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, true);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doTask, 5000, 5000);
```

Another method I tried was to create a new RetrieveColorTask in the TimerTask but then I don't know if the old thread has finished running yet, and ends up creating multiple AsyncTasks, most of them in the WAIT state. The most progress I have had is with this code:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    final RetrieveColorTask[] task = new RetrieveColorTask[1];
    final AsyncTask.Status[] status = new AsyncTask.Status[1];
    final boolean[] isRun = {false};
    TimerTask doTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(task[0] == null) {
                task[0] = new RetrieveColorTask();
                status[0] = task[0].getStatus();
                task[0].executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, true);
            } else {
                if(status[0].compareTo(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) == 0) {
                    task[0] = new RetrieveColorTask();
                    task[0].executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, true);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doTask, 5000, 5000);
```

But once the task executes the first time, it stays in PENDING state after that, so it is only run once.

I am fairly new to Android programming so I would appreciate any advice

Comment: use thread pool concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the line

```
status[0] = task[0].getStatus();
```

at the beginning of the `run()`-method so that it updates the local status variable every time the method is executed by the `TimerTask`, because right now you are storing the status of the task when it is first created, but you don't update it when the method is ran again after 5 seconds and `task[0]` is not null anymore.

Also, I would suggest that you to create a regular variable to put the task and status in just to make it cleaner, instead of using arrays because you are initializing them with only one element anyways, so in other words declare the task and the status variables like this instead:

```
RetrieveColorTask task = null;
RetrieveColorTask.Status status = null;
```

And also, personally I would do the status check like this

```
if(status == RetrieveColorTask.Status.FINISHED) ...
```

instead of using the `compareTo()` methods, because you never make use of the `1` or `-1` values that it could also possibly return.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I added the status update and it works now (glaring error I should have seen). I'm checking the debug threads and for some reason it still has a bunch of tasks alive even though it functions correctly i.e. a new thread starts after the old one finishes, but the old ones remain in a WAIT state. Is this an issue?

Comment: @RuchitKank It should not be a problem, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14725199/4170242